# Reactor - vRA - Saltstack Config integration

Tags: salt-stack

Assumption

vRA to Saltstack config integration is working fine

Saltstack config accepting the keys from the minion

---

I am triggering an event from vRA when I am creating a new VM. I would like to know how the user will know that the states which triggered by the event are completed or not

For instance:

```
reactor: 
  - 'my/custom/event':
    - salt://reactor/custom.sls
```

**/srv/salt/reactor/custom.sls**

```
test_df:
  local.cmd.run:
    - tgt: "role:MyServer"
    - tgt_type: grain
    - arg:
      - df -h > /tmp/test_df.txt
```

**On Cloud-init running the following:**

```
salt-call event.send 'my/custom/event'
```

====================================================================

How the USER will find out that the event completed successfully or not, with errors or without?

Comment: Unless the reactor does something to tell them, there is no way to know, assuming the user does not have access to master logs / job cache.

Comment: thank you for the answer, so the only way is via saltstack config -> Activity -> completed or as you said master logs.

Comment: I have no experience with SaltStack Config and vRA I'm afraid. Only Salt Open. But as a customer you should have enterprise support included, so you can ask them.